# How to create SOAP web service with more than one elements in envelop using Spring-WS?

Tags: java, spring, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a "hardcoded" web service client and I need to create WS with specified XML structure which looks in SOAUP UI like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:din="http://try.com/2010/webservice/Service">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sin:AuthData>
       <!-- items -->
    </sin:AuthData>
    <sin:equestData>
      <!-- items -->
    </sin:RequestData>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There are two root elements AuthData and RequestData.
Spring-WS generates WSDL from XSD. I have a question:

Is it possible to generate the SOAP envelope from XSD similar to the structure described above?

How do I need to correct XSD to get SOAP env structure described above?

Now my XSD look like:

[image]

And I receive next wrong (for me) SOAP env structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pow="http://comp.com.ru/pow">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pow:processRequestRequest>
         <pow:authData>
          <!-- items -->
         </pow:authData>
         <pow:processRequestData>
          <!-- items -->
         </pow:processRequestData>
      </pow:processRequestRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Generally I need to pick up `authData` and `RequestData` elements to the one level up (or to delete `processRequestRequest` element).

> Spring WS offers "only" contract-first, starting from an XSD Schema

Does this mean that I should refuse to use Spring-Ws in my case?